# Is it possible to calculate $e^x$ given $2^x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, approximation

Given a value $x$, if I have a microprocessor instruction that will give me the value of $2^x$, is it possible to calculate (or approximate) the value of $e^x$ ?

Comment: $e^{x}=2^{x/\ln 2}$. So, calculate $x/\ln 2$ with multiplication by a simple precomputed constant and then use your instruction.

Comment: No, don't believe any of these guys. You cannot do that.

Comment: Or just raise it the power of $\dfrac 1 {\ln2}$.

Comment: @orion: could you please give me a hint on how to reach that expression?

Comment: @Oliver raising to the power in programming is actually done internally by converting back to exponentiation! power function is one of the worst and most complicated functions and takes up so much time that you always want to avoid it.

Comment: @user13267 it's just basic properties of exponentiation and logarithms. You can start with $a=e^{\ln a}$ where $a=2$ and see $2^x=e^{x \ln 2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$e^x = e^{\frac{x ln(2)}{ln(2)}} = e^{\frac{ln(2^x)}{ln(2)}} $